# How can I fill enclosed shapes in a line?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've used a html canvas to create this line:

> [image: a squiggly line, which loops over itself in some places to create enclosed circle and balloon shapes]

I want the loops in the line filled, so that it looks like this:

> [image: the enclosed shapes are filled in with red]

However when I fill this it simply turns into:

> [image: the beginning and end of the line have been invisibly connected, and the whole area filled in, enclosed shapes included]

I did try using paths, it was the exact same result, just with a line connecting the start to finish.

Abstraction of code:

```
var canvas = $("canvas")[0], ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.moveto(0,0);
// code to stroke path of mouse cursor;
```

How can I get my desired result and fill in *just* the enclosed shapes in the line?

Comment: Can you provide us any code?

Comment: Link to the image: http://i.imgur.com/6CtfEQB.png. Someone edit it.

Comment: Embedding instead of linking would also be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

The problem is as Brett points out that `fill()` will implicitly close the path. There is nothing we can do about this using the API so we need to use a manual approach to fill the loops as separate closed paths.

## Finding intersections

This algorithm does the following (have not checked for cases where these loops might overlap, but it should get you started). It can also be rewritten to do this in real-time while moving the mouse.

- We can iterate over all segments in the path. Compare each segment to all the others, but from current + two as the end-point of current segment would otherwise self-intersect with start point of next segment.
- If an intersection is found:

  - Build a path from the intersection point then add points using the segments between first and last intersecting line

### Example

[image: result]

```js
var points = [49,40,49,41,49,42,49,43,49,45,49,48,49,50,49,53,49,56,49,59,49,63,49,67,49,72,50,77,51,82,53,88,53,91,55,96,58,99,60,104,62,106,64,109,65,113,68,116,70,118,72,120,74,121,76,124,78,125,81,126,87,129,92,130,98,133,104,134,109,135,113,135,117,135,121,135,127,135,131,135,135,135,141,132,148,128,153,126,159,122,161,120,164,118,164,116,165,112,165,110,165,107,165,105,165,104,165,101,165,100,164,96,163,94,162,93,160,91,159,90,158,88,157,88,156,88,154,88,151,88,147,88,141,90,135,92,130,94,126,96,121,99,118,101,114,104,111,108,108,110,107,113,104,117,103,120,100,125,99,129,96,135,95,139,95,144,95,148,95,152,95,155,95,158,96,162,97,166,99,170,102,173,106,177,109,181,111,182,113,184,115,185,117,186,119,186,121,186,124,186,127,186,132,185,135,183,141,179,146,175,152,172,158,168,165,165,172,162,178,159,185,158,191,157,195,156,199,156,202,156,206,156,209,156,212,157,216,160,220,163,221,168,224,170,224,173,225,177,227,182,228,186,229,192,229,197,230,203,230,208,230,212,230,219,230,225,230,230,228,236,226,240,221,246,217,251,214,255,210,257,204,260,199,260,194,261,189,261,184,261,181,261,177,261,175,261,173,260,173,256,171,252,170,245,170,237,169,231,168,226,168,221,168,218,168,215,168,212,168,211,169,207,172,205,175,201,180,199,187,198,194,196,201,194,208,194,214,194,221,194,225,194,230,195,235,196,240,199,245,202,247,204,251,207,253,210,254,214,255,216,259,223,263,229,266,235,270,241,273,245,277,253,279,257,283,262,287,269,292,274,297,280,302,285,308,290,314,294,321,295,327,296,336,298,343,298,352,298,359,298,367,292,374,286,379,278,381,269,381,262,381,254,381,246,381,241,379,232,377,229,372,224,369,221,364,219,361,219,355,218,347,218,339,218,330,218,320,221,310,228,300,235,290,242,282,249,276,257,271,263,269,269,267,276,266,281,266,287,266,291,267,297,272,305,279,312,286,319,296,327,305,332,316,338,325,341,333,344,340,348,342,348,344,349,345,349,345,350,346,351,347,353,347,355,347,356,347,358,347,361,347,363,347,366,347,370,347,374,344,379,343,384,342,393,339,400,335,406,331,414,323,421,317,426,310,430,302,435,295,437],
    ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    i, y, ip, t, l = points.length;

// compare each segments
for(i = 0; i < points.length - 4; i += 2) {
  for(y = i + 4; y < points.length - 2; y += 2) {
    
    ip = intersection(points[i], points[i+1], points[i+2], points[i+3],
                      points[y], points[y+1], points[y+2], points[y+3]);
    
    // any intersction? create a sub-path with segments between the intersecting lines
    if (ip) {
      ctx.moveTo(ip.x, ip.y);
      for(t = i + 2; t < y; t += 2) ctx.lineTo(points[t], points[t+1]);
    }
  } 
}

// fill all sub-paths at once
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();

// stroke path itself
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(points[0], points[1]);
for(i = 0; i < l; i += 2) ctx.lineTo(points[i], points[i+1]);
ctx.stroke();

function intersection(p0x, p0y, p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p3x, p3y) {

  var d1x = p1x - p0x, d1y = p1y - p0y,
      d2x = p3x - p2x, d2y = p3y - p2y,
      d = d1x * d2y - d2x * d1y,
      px, py, s, t;

    if (d) {
      px = p0x - p2x;
      py = p0y - p2y;
      s = (d1x * py - d1y * px) / d;
      if (s >= 0 && s <= 1) {
        t = (d2x * py - d2y * px) / d;
        if (t >= 0 && t <= 1) return {x: p0x + (t * d1x), y: p0y + (t * d1y)};
      }
    }
    return null
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: Great stuff! I've been thinking all night about this problem.

Comment: If you consider the intersections as nodes. Then create a forward fill path till you reach the end, then continue the path back on its self.When you encounter a node skip the line inside the node and continue backtracking until you reach the beginning. Then just do a single fill. If you count the number of nodes in a node you can also then add logic to not skip a node if it has sub nodes and thus you cover loops in loops. There are a range of simple rules that can create a huge range of FX using that method

Comment: Great answer, I'll try to reform this code to fit my context :D

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the `fill()` method is closing the path, basically drawing a line from the start point to the end point. The result is the entire path is filled as you've seen.

One possible solution, though it will be tough with the seemingly random line you have, is to return the pointer to a position where the `fill()` won't cause unwanted fills. The example below demonstrates this. After drawing the line I simply return the pointer to a position where the `closePath()` doesn't cause any closed regions to fill.

The canvas on the right has the final point moved to a neutral position to the `fill()` behaves as desired.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 20);
context.lineTo(100, 120);
context.lineTo(150, 120);
context.lineTo(150, 70);
context.lineTo(50, 70);

context.fill();

context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.stroke();

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 20);
context.lineTo(100, 120);
context.lineTo(150, 120);
context.lineTo(150, 70);
context.lineTo(50, 70);

// Go back to a position the line
// won't cause unwanted fills
context.lineTo(100, 70);

context.fill();

context.lineWidth = 2;
context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
context.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I guess I'll just quit.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do? Perhaps there are other solutions.

Comment: Make the line follow users cursor, when they loop, the area inside changes colour